# appengine dynamic backends how to increase idle time?

Tags: google-app-engine

The dynamic backend goes down after 2-4 minutes of idle time. Is there a way to increase this idle time? Because in my app I need do some initialization which will take time, and the time interval between 2 requests may exceed 5-10 minutes. If the instance goes down I need to again do the initialization.

I can't use resident backends because I need programmatic (from normal - frontend) way to start/stop the instance which is not possible currently.

Thanks
Adhi

Comment: Can you tell us more about why you're using backends in the first place? Maybe they're not the best choice for what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

You could rely on tasks queue to keep the backend alive.

Using the target argument, you can target backend with Push Queues as explained in the [documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-push.html#Push_Queues_and_Backends)

Using the [eta](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/tasks.html#eta_arg) argument, you could fire N noop task every minute to make sure the backend stay alive for at least N minutes after each request.

Hope that helps.